# How to hide Reporting Service's details

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is there any way of hide the details (Date) of URL in Reporting Services?

```
miércoles, 31 de octubre de 2018 16:16        <dir> Gestion de Cobranzas
      jueves, 17 de mayo de 2018 18:48        <dir> Gestión Proveedores
      viernes, 18 de mayo de 2018 9:59        <dir> IT
      lunes, 28 de enero de 2019 10:05        <dir> Reportes Comerciales miércoles, 12 de septiembre de 2018 13:12        <dir> Reportes Operativos
      viernes, 18 de mayo de 2018 9:46        <dir> Reportes RRHH   miércoles, 04 de julio de 2018 15:11        <dir> Reportes RRHH Sucursales miércoles, 28 de noviembre de 2018 15:31         <ds> Servidor de Reportes
```

I'm using **SSRR2012**

Comment: Is that supposed to be the home page of SSRS? If so maybe post a screenshot to clarify.

Comment: If thats the case then the answer is no anyway https://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=187395